# How to detect uninstall shutdown reason on disabled addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

So on shutdown if the addon is disabled, and user clicks "remove" then the uninstall reason doesnt fire. (no reasons fire) How to detect this uninstall from a disabled addon?

I need to know because on uninstall I delete the pref branch.

```
function shutdown(aData, aReason) {
    console.log('shutdown reason = ', aReason);
    if (aReason == APP_SHUTDOWN) return;
    windowListener.unregister();

    //start pref stuff more
    myPrefListener.unregister();
    if ([ADDON_UNINSTALL].indexOf(aReason) > -1) {
        console.log('deleting branch of: ' + prefPrefix);
        Services.prefs.deleteBranch(prefPrefix);
    }
    //end pref stuff more
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [implement `uninstall`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions#uninstall) which is supposed to be called when uninstalling add-ons even if the add-on is disabled.

Comment: Ah i had tried this but it's the way to go. What confused is whe nI clicked `Remove` from addon manager it wouldnt trigger it, then i would install it again and it would fire the uninstall of the last on install of the next. I realize now it's a soft uninstall until the `Undo` buttons go away. Cool man I got it now thanks! :)

Comment: Update if you want to implement `uninstall` you MUST implement `install`, giving it simple arguments will do the trick, otherwise `uninstall` will never trigger. So a simple `function install(a,b){}` will be enough. But a `function install(){}` will not be enough to trigger `uninstall`

Comment: @Noitidart, not sure where you got this, but it is simply not true that you have to implement `install`. You can have `install` as an empty function. In fact you don't even have to provide `install` at all (although the `AddonManager` will dump a warning, but execute `uninstall` nonetheless)

Comment: Are you sure man? I tested this a couple months ago and then updated the MDN docs. I'll have to retest and maybe undo MDN update then.. :/

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, and just tested using: https://gist.github.com/3a28d565811989c7deef and it indeed logged all three things.

Comment: Dang ok ill fix mdn. Do you have an addon or something that install extensions from gists? I was thinking of modifying [GitHub :: Noitidart / GitHubExtIns](https://github.com/Noitidart/GitHubExtIns) to do that. I already edited to install from edit pages of GitHub.

Comment: What about if uninstall triggers if you have an empty install? Like `function install() { }` maybe that's what I hit and it was a bug.

Comment: @Noitidart, having a defined but empty `install` will also call `uninstall` correctly. You really should "unedit" your MDN stuff. https://gist.github.com/515c7da04a85575eb124

Comment: Crap you're right. https://github.com/Noitidart/PortableTester I edited it out, it was on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions#uninstall